# JavaScript Regex - match last 2 digits and check within numeric range

Tags: javascript, regex, range

I have a string such as "33232323232120" which can be of different lengths. I would like to select the last two digits and check they are in a range e.g. the number must be between 0 and 5 for example.

Heres what I have so far:

```
\d{1}[0-5]$
```

This correctly matches on the last 2 digits however incorrectly matches on "20" in the example above i.e. the number is not between 0 and 5.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Do you need to do it in one regexp call? Would substring-ing off the last two characters, parsing them to int, and then testing them work?

Comment: *the number must be between 0 and 20 for example*, but then *incorrectly matches on "20"* Which is it? is 20 acceptable or not? *the number is not between 0 and 5* Where did the 0 to 5 come from?

Comment: Apologies. I edited the example to be clearer. If the range is between 0 and 5, 20 should not match.

Comment: Do you mean `/0[0-5]$/`?

Comment: 1. Check `(^\d+$)`
 2. Then `(\d{2}$)` 3. Then Check `0=<digit<=20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need

```
[01][0-9]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO5kL8/1)

The `[01]` matches `1` or `0`, and `[0-9]` matches any digit. So, you match  from `00` to `19`.

```js
var vals = ["33232323232120","23445301","23445302","23445303","23445304","23445305","23445306","23445307","23445308","23445309","234453010","245841511","245841512","245841513","245841514","245841515","245841516","245841517","245841518","245841519","521","531"];
var rx = /[01][0-9]$/;

// Demo

document.body.innerHTML += "Pattern: <b>" + rx.source + "</b><br/>";                               
for (var s = 0; s < vals.length; s++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += "Testing \"<i>" + vals[s] + "</i>\"... ";
  document.body.innerHTML += "Matched: <b>" + rx.test(vals[s]) + "</b><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Great stuff! Many thanks for the explanation, super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think to select any last 2 digits you can use `\d{2}$`
If you want to select the last number even when it is only a single digit (0-9) you can use `\d{2}$|\d$`

Your regex works inside my trial [here](https://regex101.com/r/rF5vO7/3)
From my understanding your code will select the last 2 digits for all tens and units ranging from 0-5

Comment: many thanks however in my example 20 is selected however 20 is not greater than 0 and lower than 5 i.e. in range.

Comment: In the case you only want to get 01,02,03,04,05 you can use this regex `[0][0-5]$`<br>
this will only return those number I specified above